# How to search files by file icon

Tags: windows-7

I have an EXE file with an icon associated with it. I want to search several systems for the same icon.

The EXE name could be different on every system (It's a random string 12 characters long).  But the icon seems to stay the same.

How would I go about searching for all files with this particular icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It's possible

Use a combination of PowerShell, [IconsExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) and [ConsoleImageComparison](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/374386/Simple-image-comparison-in-NET).

1. Extract all icons from all EXE files in a given folder and its subfolders using IconsExtract
2. Compare each extracted icon with the original reference icon using ConsoleImageComparison
   It graphically compares two images and gives back a percentage of how high the difference is.
3. At last, sort all results by difference percentage and save it into a CSV to see the best matches first

### Example output

Here I searched for the old Opera icon. I see that there are 3 files containing my icon because they have a difference of 0% to our reference icon. Beside the extracted icon name I also got the path where the source file resides.

[image]

### IconsExtract

We use Nirsoft's [IconsExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) to scan a given file and extract each possible icon. Remember, a single EXE or DLL can have multiple icons in it. The `-icons` switch tells the program to only extract ICO files and leave out PNG or cursor files.

```
iconsext.exe /save "source file" "save folder" [-icons] [-cursors] [-asico]
```

We extract all icons to a temp folder and iterate through each icon and compare it. After it, we empty the temp folder and extract the next EXE file into the same temp folder. So we're doing a lot of creating and deleting of small files.

One problem is, visually identical icons can have multiple size versions (32x32 vs. 255x255) and our comparison will detect huge differences. That's a problem for [ImageMagick's compare](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compare) tool for example.

Another problem are different image headers. Even if the extension is ICO, the actual image type is identified using some unique bytes from the file content. Extension and content can differ. This is a problem for [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/), a fork from ImageMagick.

### ConsoleImageComparison

Luckily, after some hours I found ConsoleImageComparison on www.codeproject.com. We use the command line ability, but it also has a GUI.

```
ImageComparisonConsole.exe [image1 path] [image2 path]
```

[image]

### PowerShell

Now comes the hard part. We have to put all these pieces together. Since you're on Windows, I prefer PowerShell. Of course you can use any other scripting language like Linux bash or Windows batch if you want

Per comparison, you get a string like `Difference is 80%`. We use the RegEx pattern
`(?<=Difference is )\d+` to extract the numerical value and add it to an array. From there we just sort the array and output it to a tab delimited CSV. Nothing fancy.

```mumps
$folder       = "D:\Browser\Internet\Browser"
$icon         = "C:\Users\Nixda\Desktop\Opera.ico"  
$scriptFolder = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$iconExt      = "$scriptFolder\iconsext.exe"
$CIC          = "$scriptFolder\ConsoleImageComparison.exe"

$results = @()
get-childitem -path $folder -recurse -include @("*.exe") | foreach {

    & $iconExt /save $_.Fullname "$scriptFolder\temp" -icons |out-null
    $file =  $_.fullname

    get-childitem -path "$scriptFolder\temp" | foreach {

        $percent = & $CIC $icon $_.Fullname | 
          Select-String '(?<=Difference is )\d+' | 
          % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }        

        $results += ,@([int]$percent, $_.Name, $file)
    }    

    remove-item "$scriptFolder\temp" -recurse | out-null
}
$results | sort-object @{Expression={$_[0]}; Ascending=$true} | 
  % { $_ -join "`t" } | 
  out-File "$scriptFolder\result.csv"

& "$scriptFolder\result.csv"
```

### How to use

1. Download [IconsExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) and [ConsoleImageComparison](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/374386/ConsoleImageComparison_1.6.zip) and save them to a folder
2. Open a new text file, paste the code above and save it as `SearchByIcon.ps1` to the same folder. You should now have three files in one folder
3. Change the `$folder` variable to your root folder where the script should start to search. I looks in all subfolders, but only for EXE files. You can change this behavior
4. Change the `$icon` variable to your reference icon which should be searched for
5. Right-click on `SearchByIcon.ps1` and select *Run with PowerShell*. Depending on how many EXE files you have, the program takes a while to finish

That's all. Have fun.

<sup>I got some out-of-memory errors from ConsoleImageComparison. But it seems not to affect the result or abort the program</sup>

Comment: Now, when I reread your question, I forgot one small step. You have to manually extract the icon from your original EXE one time. I just passed the ICO path to the script, but that's not a big deal